# How to use tuples as function arguments?

Tags: python

For example if we take the build-in function `pow`,
and I have:

```
c= (2,3)
```

How do I calculate `pow(2,3)` using the tuple `c`?

Comment: You call it with an asterisk for tuple unpacking, so `pow(*c)`...

Comment: Thank you. Is this method safe though? Will it unpack the tuple in its original inner order?

Comment: Yes, tuples are ordered and remain the same order when unpacked

Comment: Yes, it always unpacks the tuple in the order of the elements. The elements you give to `pow` are unnamed, so the order in which the parameters of `pow` are defined is used.